# Maven - package does not exist, same package name prefix

Tags: java, maven

I have two Spring Boot projects. Project A has package com.abc.service. Project B has package com.abc.core.dto. Both have the same group ids.

I want to use the classes from Project B on Project A. I compiled and built Project B and imported it to Project A through pom.xml, however, I can't import it as I'm receiving "package com.abc.core.dto does not exist" error.

Am I correct that I can't use the same package prefix across different projects?

Thanks.

Comment: yes, it is possible and normal. Seems, you missed something in: 1. "compile & build B" (`mvn package` should be enough for most IDE's, `mvn install` is safer) or 2. "imported to A" (adding B as a `compile` dependency to A, should make all packages of B importable/accesible)

Comment: Well, I did `mvn install` of Project B, and the pom.xml of Project A is seeing the imported dependency just fine. It is inside the class files I can't use Project B's classes.

Answer (score 0):

I added Project B through the "Add Maven Projects" button on IntelliJ's Maven tab and the Project A started to compile without errors. So I guess the error was associated with IntelliJ.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).